# Deploying to Azure WebSites using git

Tags: git, azure, azure-web-app-service

From a local git repository with an azure remote. As well as with a Github repository.

Get the following errors:

```
error: unable to create file public/css/sass/....
 (Invalid argument)
error: unable to create file public/css/sass/....
 (Invalid argument)
error: unable to create file public/css/sass/global/Icon
 (Invalid argument)
error: unable to create file public/css/sass/....
 (Invalid argument)
error: unable to create file public/css/sass/....
 (Invalid argument)
error: unable to create file public/css/sass/....
 (Invalid argument)
error: unable to create file public/css/sass/....
 (Invalid argument)
Previous HEAD position was ac5daq1... initial deploy
Switched to branch 'azure'

D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe checkout azure --force
```

Any insight into what is even causing this would be fantastic.

Comment: Some possibilities: invalid path name on Windows, corrupted repo etc... Does your repo have this problem before?

Comment: oh windows... had some files with illegal characters..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cswimmer` has pointed out the correct problem. I had been looking for the reasons, why my deployment is being failed. After going through this post, I found out the file being created had characters in name, which are not allowed in windows. *(eg, file name `2016-06-19_09:55:25_4_13_3_1_0` isn't allowed in windows)*